# Can't boot into legacy SeaBIOS

Tags: linux, boot-loader, firmware, chrome-os, chromium-os

I have a Acer CB3-111 Chromebook, and am trying to run Debian wheezy

Following tutorials online, I managed to:

- Put machine into developer mode
- Enable legacy SeaBIOS (`crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1`)
- Create USB Debian installer

However, when I try to enter the SeaBIOS menu during boot (by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>), I instead hear two loud beeps. At this screen, by pressing tab, I can verify that `dev_boot_usb=1` and `dev_boot_legacy=1`...

Granted, the tutorials generally feature the Acer C720.
How can I get this to work?

Comment: "I have tried, but can't seem to get my machine to boot into legacy SeaBIOS so I can choose boot device?" why don't you ask about that issue instead?

Comment: @Braiam OK! Rephrasing..

Comment: @Braiam how is this?